# How to make a regex string to not allow single quotes except if it is preceded by a slash?

Tags: javascript

How to make a regex string to not allow single quotes except if it is preceded by a slash?
Right now we are using '(.*)' but this is bad practice.

Allowed strings:
'Hello how are you?'
'We\'ll do it'

Forbidden strings:
'We'll do it'

PS: The way I tested this is by using regex101.com

Comment: Can you explain the use-case? It feels like you are doing something really wrong...

Comment: I don't think regex is the right tool for character escaping. Because: According to you question, `We\\'ll do it` would be allowed, while here the slash is escaped, not the single quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assert that the string, from beginning (`^`) to end (`$`), is composed of any number (`*`) of `\'` pairs or (`|`) any non-single-quote character (`[^']`).

```js
const re    = /^(\\'|[^'])*$/;
const valid = str => re.test(str);
var inputs  = ["Hello how are you?", "We\\'ll do it", "We'll do it"];

inputs.forEach(sentence => console.log(sentence, valid(sentence)));
```

Alternatively, unless you need a single regexp which matches or does not match, you can write a regex which matches if there is an invalid sequence, then check to see if it **doesn't** match:

```js
const re    = /(^|[^\\])'/;
const valid = str => !re.test(str);
var inputs  = ["Hello how are you?", "We\\'ll do it", "We'll do it"];

inputs.forEach(sentence => console.log(sentence, valid(sentence)));
```

The `^` at the beginning is necessary to match (meaning invalid) if the single quote occurs at the beginning of the input string.

Comment: I like this: `^(\\'|[^'])*$` very elegant!

Comment: OMG... this is so much better than my solution

Answer (score 0):

This is my third attempt at a solution to your question.

The second attempt was more sophisticated than the first, but I've just learned how **regex lookbehinds** work and this time I think I have fundamentally cracked it.

This regex:

```
^([^']*(?<=\\)')*[^']*$
```

- (`^`) - Starts at `^`
- (`[^']*$`) - Finishes with 0 to any number of characters which are *not* `'`
- (`([^']*(?<=\\)')*`) - Between the start and the finish, has 0 to any number of character combinations which...
- (`[^']*`) - start with 0 to any number of characters which are not `'`
- (`(?<=\\)'`) - and are then followed by a `'` which is immediately preceded by a `\`.

---

Thanks (as always) to *Rexegg*, my favourite Regex tutorial site:

http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html

Comment: Is that valid in JS-flavored regexps?

Comment: Hmm... good question. I was testing it in PCRE, but now I read that _JavaScript regular expressions do not support lookbehinds_. Except... that may be about to change very soon / is changing / has already changed, given this Feb 2016 update from the V8 Javascript blog: http://v8project.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/regexp-lookbehind-assertions.html

Comment: I'm puzzled why an answer using a feature (look-behinds) which is not supported in JS would be marked as accepted. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your full requirements but, `string.replace("'","\\'")` would be my approach. So instead of not allowing single quotes not preceded by a backslash, I would simply inject a backslash behind every single quote I find.

```js
var userString = "we'll do it"
console.log(userString.replace("'","\\'"))
```